# angularjs $http.get not working on mobile browsers

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I tried to use this code:

```
var url = "http://www.test.com?param=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK"; 

$http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

if (data.success == 1) {

    //do somethings

} else {

    //notice

}

});
```

It is working fine with browsers of laptop but on mobile browsers, it is not working.

in .htaccess, i added:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, content-type"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Please help!

Comment: I think it's not related to mobile and laptop it's due to the version of the browser. I think your application is not hosted it http://www.test.com and now you're sending ajax request to a different domain and the browser is blocking it.

Comment: Either you can deploy the application in the same domain where you're sending the ajax request and if it's not possible then enable cors in the  http://www.test.com

Comment: You can check your domain access by any rest client which will help to understand if the rest server is available to you.

Comment: test.com is an example, i am calling the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile browser and desktop browser works same way for http calls. You can make an error block in your code to see what error is coming from the server. Below piece of code is what I am suggesting.

```
this._getAll = function (model) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http
        .get("your-secure-rest-url")
        .success(function (data) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function (reason) {
          deferred.reject(reason);
        });
      return deferred.promise;
 };
```

As you are allowing Access origin "*" for all domain, there is no problem in client side but you need to check the rest server if it is accessable from all domain or is it restricted to particular domain.

Comment: The cross orgin problem is obviously from server side. Thus adding $q in the frontend will not make any difference at all.

Comment: Yes, I just provided a better method to work and sync with the server. In my answer I clearly mentioned to add error block so that you can catch the error returning from the server.  The $q service is promise api which you can consider as best practice while making external calls.

Comment: Hello, i found this problem. It is from my php code, thanks for your help